# Undefined variable: $_SESSION Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5, moodle

I have problem when get PHP superglobal variable `$_SESSION` from inside laravel controller.

I can get Moodle session from laravel. I can get moodle session in laravel with `$_SESSION['USER']` using [this example](https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=252495), but if I run `php artisan route:list` it returns an error, like this:

[image]

So I cannot use the Laravel redirect function.
Can anyone help me with this?
Is there any other way to call the superglobal `$_SESSION` in the Laravel controller?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can use session functions provided by laravel

Save something on session variable

```
 Session::put('name', 'yourname');
```

Retrieve

```
Session::get('name')
```

Unset

```
Session::forget('name');
```